# Email sending via Android Application

Tags: android

I want to send email from my application without configuration email in android device.
can we do this?? we click a button and mail will automatically to the recipient.

I have used the following code. where we can give the sender name. 
and can we send mail via android emulator.

Thanx.

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"abc@example.com"});
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Request For Quote");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Hi....");
                try {
                    //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //Toast.makeText(SendingEmailActivity.this, "Mail Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(DemoActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread

> [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Without any intervention, you couldn't use Intents.

Take a look at [This tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) about javamail and android